# Magento 2 Checkout template translation not working

Tags: templates, translation, magento2.2

Any idea why the Magento_Checkout template retrieves translation from Magento_Customer?

Is there a way to force the template to use the specific entry for Magento_Checkout ?

Here is the path of template and the html code in it:

> app/code/Snowdog/theme-blank-sass/Magento_Checkout/web/template/authentication.html

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Forgot Your Password?'"></span>
```

Here is the dictionary path and the entries in it:

> app/i18n/VendorName/chinese-language-pack/zh_Hans_CN.csv

```
"Forgot Your Password?","您忘记密码了吗? - Checkout",module,Magento_Checkout
"Forgot Your Password?","您忘记密码了吗? - Customer",module,Magento_Customer
"Forgot your password?","您忘记密码了吗? - User",module,Magento_User
```

Here is the actual output, currently being displayed in the checkout page

```
<span>您忘记密码了吗? - Customer</span>
```

Here is the desired output that needs to be shown in the checkout page

```
<span>您忘记密码了吗? - Checkout</span>
```